# IBM Notes plugin CSIViewPart viewActions

Tags: eclipse, view, action, lotus-notes

I have successfully added a viewAction to the IBM Notes E-Mail/Calendar application. But it is located at the incorrect location.

It is currently located at:

```
[New ▼][Reply ▼][Reply to All ▼]...[My Action]
```

I would like it to become a child menu item of the New button.

```
[New ▼]______
|Meeting     |
|Appointment |
|Event       |
|My Action   |
|____________|
```

How can I find the toolbarPath to this location?

And how would I be able to make this action only appear in the in the calendar application?

Thanks,
Stijn

Comment: Try renaming your action to "New\My Action"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this, but it does not work. It looks like the new/reply etc. actions are added after the initiation of the view. My action is visible before the new button appears.